# How to write code that runs once

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Basically, I have a page with two forms, both using the same code to validate data:

```
public ActionResult DoValCheck(ValidationCheckObject aValCheckHelper)
    {
        var recID = int.Parse(aValCheckHelper.RecordID);
        var hicnExists = UnitOfWork.McaUniqueRecordRepository.FindBy(m => m.HICN == aValCheckHelper.HICN);
        var ssnExists = UnitOfWork.McaUniqueRecordRepository.FindBy(m => m.Injured_Party.SSN == aValCheckHelper.SSN);

        if ((UnitOfWork.McaUniqueRecordRepository.FindBy(m => m.Record_ID == recID && m.HICN == aValCheckHelper.HICN).Any()) ||
             UnitOfWork.McaUniqueRecordRepository.FindBy(m => m.Record_ID == recID && m.Injured_Party.SSN == aValCheckHelper.SSN).Any())
        {
            return Json(false);
        }

        if (hicnExists.Any())
        {
            return Json(new { Success = hicnExists.Any(), RecordID = (hicnExists.Any() ? hicnExists.First().Record_ID : -1) });

        }
        if (ssnExists.Any())
        {

            return Json(new { Success = ssnExists.Any(), RecordID = (ssnExists.Any() ? ssnExists.First().Record_ID : -1) });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that this code is set to run any time the condition is true...so any time `hicnExists.Any()` is true, this code runs (this code is called in my JavaScript, but I'd rather deal with one piece at a time). That is to say, any time there is code in the HICN text field, `hicnExists.Any()` will be true.

What can I do to only allow this code to run once?

Comment: You could create a file. If that file exists, it's been ran before. If it doesn't exist, it hasn't been ran before.

Answer (score 0):

Make `hicnExists` a nullable static class-level variable. Test to see if it's null when your function is called. If it's null, run your query and set the value. Once the value is set, the query will not run again for the remainder of the current transaction.

If you want to cache the result between transactions, then I recommend setting a session cookie or making use of server-side session variables.